# Reproducing a picture (fuel assembly) using Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I am trying to write the code to draw the picture below in TikZ. My code is necessarily long with lots of `\foreach` loops. Could you please give guidance on how to reproduce this picture in TikZ.

[image]

Comment: Could you share your ongoing code to work on it editing your question please ? Thanks

Comment: Welcome! Since you have some code, please post that as @PMC1234 requested, and tell us what exactly you are having trouble with. It would help, too, to know what matters about the diagram you posted. What is important and what not?

Answer (score 3):

Don't know if this captures what matters, but here's a start.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt,multi]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \fill [fill=blue!75!green!85!yellow] (-5.1,-8.1) rectangle (5.1,8.1);
  \foreach \i in {-3,...,3} \draw (\i,-8) -- (\i,8);
  \filldraw [fill=green] (-4,-8) rectangle (-4.25,8) (4,-8) rectangle (4.25,8);
  \filldraw [fill=blue!75!green!90!cyan] (-4.25,-8) rectangle (4.25,-7.65) (-4.25,8) rectangle (4.25,7.65);
  \foreach \i in {-7.15,-6.4,...,7.15}
  {
    \draw [double=blue!75!green!90!cyan, draw=green, double distance=4mm, line width=.5mm] (-4.25,\i) -- (4.25,\i);
    \draw (-4.25,\i) ++(0,-2.5mm) -- +(8.5,0)  (-4.25,\i) ++(0,-2mm) -- +(8.5,0)  (-4.25,\i) ++(0,2.5mm) -- +(8.5,0)  (-4.25,\i) ++(0,2mm) -- +(8.5,0);
  }
  \filldraw [fill=yellow] (-5,-8) rectangle (-4.25,8) (5,-8) rectangle (4.25,8);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: venetian blinds]

Comment: Nice one @cfr !