# Using \foreach for repeated structure

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

```
documentclass[border={5mm}]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,
    default rectangle/.style={rectangle, draw=black,thin, minimum size=1cm},    
    ]
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------
% fuel Assembly
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Water around the assembly

 \foreach \x in {-10,-5}{
    \foreach \y in {-1,4}{
      \draw[black,very thin, fill=blue!50!white] (\x,\y) rectangle (-10,4);

% side plate left

       \foreach \x in {-9.9,-9.4}{
         \foreach \y in {-0.9,3.9}{      
           \draw[black,very thin, fill=gray!20!white] (\x,\y) rectangle (-9.4,3.9);

% side plate right

           \foreach \x in {-5.6,-5.1}{
            \foreach \y in {-0.9,3.9}{      
              \draw[black,very thin, fill=gray!20!white] (\x,\y) rectangle (-5.1,3.9);

% 19 fuel plates 

               \foreach \position in {(-5.6,-0.8)}{
                 \draw[black,very thin, fill=gray!50!white] \position rectangle (-9.4,-0.7);


                  }
                }
              }
             }
           }
         }
       }

 \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I am trying to reproduce the picture of a fuel assembly below. My problem is to repeat the 19 plates of the assembly using the loops, i.e. \foreach. Is there a way to avoid repeating the use of \foreach loop for all the 19 plates? Basically I need to build the plate once and just repeat it 19 times as in the attached picture. Thanking you in advance for your assistance. [image]

Comment: Didn't [this previous question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/286560/4778) solve this problem? cfr's answer there has only two foreach loops.

Comment: @Alenanno It is a different user? But the same question?

Comment: Is this a question in someone's homework or something? Seems weird to get 2 questions asking to draw *just this* so close together.... I guess the colours are slightly different in this one.

Answer (score 4):

Tikz includes the calc package by default. That means you can use normal operations like + and -. To draw the included picture I would use something like this.

```
\documentclass[border={5mm}]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,
  default rectangle/.style={rectangle, draw=black,thin, minimum size=1cm}]
  % ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  % fuel Assembly
  % ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  % Water around the assembly
  \def\numRep{19}
  \def\Marg{0.1}
  \draw[blue,fill=blue](0-\Marg,0-\Marg) rectangle (15+\Marg,\numRep+\Marg);
  \foreach \Y in {1,2,...,\numRep}{
    \draw[blue,fill=green] (0,\Y-1) rectangle (15,\Y);
    \draw[blue,fill=blue] (1,\Y-1) rectangle (14,\Y-0.65);
    \draw[blue,fill=blue] (1,\Y-0.35) rectangle (14,\Y);
    \draw[blue,fill=red] (1.5,\Y-0.55) rectangle (13.5,\Y-0.45);
    %% Lines horisontal
    \foreach \Yline in {0.35,0.45,0.55,0.65} \draw[blue] (1,\Y-\Yline) -- +(13,0);
  };
  %% Lines vertical
  \foreach \Xline in {0,1,...,6} \draw[blue] (2*\Xline+1.5,0) -- +(0,\numRep);
  \draw[blue] (1,0) -- +(0,\numRep);
  \draw[blue] (14,0) -- +(0,\numRep);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice solution! What is purposes of code line  `default rectangle/.style={rectangle, draw=black,thin, minimum size=1cm}`? It seems that it is surplus.

Comment: @Zarko, yes you are right. The optional parameters for tikzpicture is a copy-paste from the question and can be removed. scale=1 is default and the other is not used.